# Can I change a read/write .dmg file to read-only without copying?

Tags: disk-utility, hdiutil

I'm working on some automation for ingesting media from camera cards.  I am using `hdiutil` to create a blank disk image, then copy the contents of the camera card onto that disk image.  Then I'd love to change that disk image to "Read-only" **without** having to create any kind of copy of the disk image.  I'm trying to optimize this process for speed, hence creating a blank disc image and copying files to it (much faster than creating a disc image fo the drive in my tests)

Comment: can't you use chmod from command line?

Comment: try `hdiutil convert /path/to/rwimage.dmg -format UDRO -o /path/to/readonlyimage.dmg`

Comment: @jmh Looks like I can make a UDRW image unable to be written to without the admin password via this method, but it does not go the other way to change a read-only image to read and write.  Plus I'm not sure if an ACL will supersede that, I'll have to try it.  I guess that's an acceptable workaround but not ideal.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm trying not to create a copy of the dmg since some of these .dmg files are over 100Gb